# In AWS, how can I get physical instance ID from instance id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When we use small AWS instnaces (e.g., d2.xlarge etc.), it is possible that multiple instances are allocated to the same host. I want to check if two vm instances are on the same host. Is there a way for us to get the physical instance ID of vms?  With this info, we can check if two instances are on the same physical host.

The primary motivation behind this is to improve the reliability of running stateful service in the cloud. We use d2.xlarge instances to run hbase/kafka workload in the cloud. These services require data replicatio. As one physical host can host up to 8 d2.xlarge instances. If one physical node is down, it may affect multiple vm instances, and cause data loss.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve with this information?

Comment: We tried to avoid placing two or more d2.xlarge instances on the same physical host -- in that case, if the underneath physical machine fails, multiple instances will go down. That will be bad for us.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Amazon wouldn't let you know anything about their underlying infrastructure. And I cannot think of a reason why they should.

But I've found this [blog post](https://huanliu.wordpress.com/2010/06/14/amazons-physical-hardware-and-ec2-compute-unit/) saying that you can use **CPUID** instruction to find out the actual CPU of the underlying physical machine.

From that post:

> The “cpuid” instruction is supported by all x86 CPU manufacturers, and
>   it is designed to report the capabilities of the CPU. This instruction
>   is non-trapping, meaning that you can execute it in user mode without
>   triggering protection trap. In the Xen paravirtualized hypervisor
>   (what Amazon uses), it means that the hypervisor would not be able to
>   intercept the instruction, and change the result that it returns.
>   Therefore, the output from “cpuid” is the real output from the
>   physical CPU.

Having that said, if you need this information to ensure they don't fail all at once, I'd recommend using launching instances from different availability zones. This way even if the whole AZ goes down you'd still have some instances up and running.

Comment: cupid cannot unqiuely identify the physical host.

Comment: I think if you are using AWS you have to adopt their rules and approach. It's not a datacentre that you have full control over so I'd recommend not worrying about the underlying physical machines and look for proper methods to achieve high availability

Comment: That's not what dedicated tenancy means.  It means that your virtual machines will not run on shared hardware.  However if you are launching dedicated tenancy machines then several of YOUR VMs can and likely will be placed on the same physical hardware.  It does not mean distinct dedicated hardware for each of your VMs.  I can confirm this as I got a 'degraded performance your instance underlying hardware will be expired' notification for TWO of my runnings VMs.

Comment: @greg_diesel: I looked into it and you're right so I removed that part. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Still I believe trying to find out the physical machine while running VMs on the cloud is futile and is absolutely the wrong way to go.

Comment: Sometime it is necessary. For instance, if we use d2.xlarge instances to run hbase/kafka workload in the cloud that involves data replication, we want to make sure that the replicas are distributed to vm instances on the physical nodes -- otherwise, if one physical node is down, it may affect multiple vm instances, and cause data loss.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official support from AWS on getting the VM placement info. Some large AWS customers are able to get customized support on this.